# Trying to animate the size of 4 images, each inside their own div?

Tags: jquery

I want to animate the size of four different small images, each inside their own div. Right now, I can animate the div, but the images inside the div don't change. Is there a way to do this?

Here is an example of what's working currently: http://jsfiddle.net/r69Zv/1/

My current javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#green_box_container a").click(function() {
          $(this).children().animate({height:105,width:105})
          $(this).siblings().children().animate({height:80,width:80})
    })
});
```

Edit: It doesn't seem to work by simply trying to enter $(this).children('img').animate ...

Any help would be awesome!!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/r69Zv/4/

Answer (score 0):

Many ways of doing this but one way is to add this CSS style

```
div img { width:100%; height:100%; }
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r69Zv/3/)

UPDATE

For what it's worth, I simplified your HTML.

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r69Zv/5/)... much simpler and cleaner.

Comment: Yeah, I can see that yours is much cleaner and simpler-- Mine is a bit more messy because of the extra divs, but it is working now!! Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Ah, there are 2 options:

1. Style your images to inherit their container's size:

   a {
       position: relative;
   }

   img {
       position: absolute;
       width: 100%;
       height: 100%;
   }
2. Resize your images as well as your their containers:

   $(document).ready(function () {
       $("#green_box_container a").click(function() {
             $(this).children().animate({height:105,width:105})
             $(this).find('img').animate({height:105,width:105})
             $(this).siblings().children().animate({height:80,width:80})
       })
   });